# Jest does not resolve lodash imports

Tags: lodash, jestjs, stenciljs

I'm writing a web component using StencilJS. One of the helper classes (`ArrayHelper.ts`) which is imported by my component has these import at the top:

```
import transform from 'lodash/transform';
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
import isObject from 'lodash/isObject';
```

this all works fine when compiling and serving locally. However, when writing some unit tests and executing them using jest, jest can't resolve these imports properly:

```
TypeError: isObject_1.default is not a function at Function.Object. 
<anonymous>.ArrayHelper.toArray (/mycomponent/ArrayHelper.ts:15:35)
```

When I change the imports in `ArrayHelper.ts` to

```
import { isEmpty, isEqual, isObject, transform } from 'lodash';
```

then Jest will succesfully run the tests without problems but then the TS compilation by stencilJS doesn't work any more:

```
Missing Export: mycomponents/ArrayHelper.js:5:27
'isObject' is not exported by node_modules/lodash/lodash.js
```

Any ideas how to get these imports right for both situations?

Comment: Wich versions of jest are you using? What's the script for testing?

Answer (score 2):

Try import lodash like this

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
```

Comment: It defeats the whole purpose of importing partial modules from lodash...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your stencil.config.js:

```
nodeResolve: {
  browser: true
}
```

This is happening because lodash is not available where Jest is running your tests. Is it an experimental browser technology.

Refer - [Link1](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2071) [Link2](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/issues/652)

Answer (score -2):

```
import * as transform from 'lodash/transform';
import * as isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';
import * as isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
import * as isObject from 'lodash/isObject';
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].